# Subscribing to depth information from zed camera

Tags: ros, camera-depth-points, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a subscriber to obtain the depth information from a zed camera.  I have written the following .cpp code:

```
//#include <iostream>
#include "ros/ros.h"
//#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"

//using namespace std;

void depthCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("Depth Info: [%d]", msg->data )
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "zed_depth_subscriber")
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth/image_rect_color",1000, depthCallback);
    ros::spin ();
    return 0;
}
```

I realize that the line: `ROS_INFO("Depth Info: [%d]", msg->data )` may throw an error (I am expecting a matrix, but not really sure how I can handle it in a ROS subscriber). But my current problem is related to CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files.

This subscriber is supposed to obtain depth information from the topic /camera/depth/image_rect_color from the [zed wrapper](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper). I am planning to add this .cpp file to

> ~/catkin_ws/src/zed-ros-wrapper/src/

and edit the CMakeLists.txt in the location:

> ~/catkin_ws/src/zed-ros-wrapper/

I am looking at the example given in [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) which gave me the following:

```
add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

I know that 'listener' should be replaced with 'zed_depth_subscriber'. But how do I identify the dependencies? How will the line `add_dependencies(....`  change?

Also do I need to edit package.xml residing in the same folder as that of CMakeLists.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239116/subscribing-to-depth-information-from-zed-camera/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out how to do it. I created a separate package for the subscriber. I have the following `depthCallback` function now:

```
void depthCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("Depth Info: [%d]", msg->data[500]);
}
```

The main dependency required is `sensor_msgs` (along with `roscpp`). The `add_dependecies(...` line in the `CmakeLists.txt` would look like:

```
add_dependencies(zed_depth_subscriber_node sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
```

The `package.xml` should have the `sensor_msgs` as run and build dependency.

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0